# dynamic property does not work with custom class

Tags: actionscript-3

This works:

```
var o:Object = {};
o['one'] = 1;
```

But if I create my class, and try the same it doenst work.

```
class MyClass {}
var m:MyClass = new MyClass;
m['one'] = 1; // Error: Not possible to create property 'one'
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
 dynamic class MyClass {}
```

If you look at the Object class it is defined like this :

```
public dynamic class Object extends *
```

You can add properties to dynamic classes at runtime.